# Using Regular Expressions, how to narrow a word down to a more accurate match

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file that consists of a HUGE list of words... 
And then I have a shortened version of the word

Example **mthr** needs to become **mother** and not **motherlessness**

Using a regular expression I need to **ONLY** bring back the consonants that are in the shortened word "mthr" and nothing else... Doing that it will bring back a more accurate word.

Does anyone know how to do that? I have been stuck on this part for most of the day.

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to go from `mother` to `mthr`, or find `mother` in the word list given `mthr`?

Comment: I need to use the word **mthr** to find in a list of words the closest match to **mother** and not 7 other words relating to it.. @Barmar

Comment: I would look at Peter Norvig's blog entry, How to Write a Spelling Corrector. http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html It does not use regular expressions, as you request, but it shows a proper algorithm for solving the problem.

Comment: When I use Norvig's spelling corrector against the ubuntu american-english dictionary, I get these candidates: ['bohr', 'ether', 'mar', 'math', 'mather', 'meir', 'meter', 'mhz', 'migr', 'mir', 'miter', 'mithra', 'moho', 'moor', 'moth', 'mother', 'moths', 'motor', 'mr', 'mt', 'muir', 'muter', 'myth', 'myths', 'nth', 'other', 'ruhr', 'schr', 'star', 'stir', 'tar', 'th', 'thar', 'the', 'tho', 'thor', 'thru', 'thur', 'thy', 'tor'] and the top choice is 'moor'.

Comment: If you had created a structure containing the shortened voweless word and the original length, those could have been used in a regex (see Barmar answer) to find the closest match. Depending, it could be up to an %80 probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regexp that will find `mother` when given the abbreviation `mthr` is:

```
^[aeiou]*m[aeiou]*t[aeiou]*h[aeiou]*r[aeiou]*$
```

I.e. given an abbreviation, put `[aeiou]*, which matches any sequence of vowels, between each letter and between the beginning and end anchors and the first/last letters.

Note that this abbreviation will also match `mauther`, `mether`, and `mouther` if they're in your word list.